# How to prove that the residual sum of squares is a non-convex Function?

Tags: convex-analysis, machine-learning, clustering

> The $K$-means algorithm uses a *residual sum of squares* (RSS) where $$ \mbox{RSS}_{K} = \sum_{d \in s}|{d-c(s)}|^2 $$

- $\mbox{RSS} = \sum_{k= 1}^K \mbox{RSS}_{K}$ is the  **convergence  criterion**. $\mbox{RSS}$ is the objective function of $K$-means and our goal is to minimize it.
- $c(s) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{|s|} \sum_{d \in s}{d}$
  where $d$ is the datapoint belonging to cluster $s$.

---

**Example.** Suppose there are 5 points in a cluster $(1,2),(2,1), (3,2), (2,2), (2,3)$. The mean point is (2,2). $\mbox{RSS}$ function takes that mean $(2,2)$ and each of those remaining 4 points and calculates the euclidean distance among them and sum over for all those 4 points

$$\left( ((1,2) - (2,2))^2 + ((2,1) - (2,2))^2 + ((3,2) - (2,2))^2 + ((2,3) - (2,2))^2 \right)$$

---

K-means algorithm is described is as following:

1. Choose the number of cluster(Basket) $K$.
2. Initialize $K$ centroids by randomly selecting $K$ vectors from the
   input
3. Assign each vector to the closest centroid.
4. Update each centroid by taking the average of the vectors belonging to
   the corresponding cluster.
5. Repeat *{Steps 3 and 4 }* **until convergence**.

---

I know that functions are either convex or non-convex. For convex function, there is one global minima, but for non-convex functions there are local minima along with global minima. Hence, $K$-means  easily falls in trap of those local minima. But I am not getting how that $\mbox{RSS}$ is a non-convex function. Can anyone please explain it to me?

[For more information about RSS](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/k-means-1.html)

**EDIT**:-  As suggested by Rodrigo, [In this lecture](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Eabandeira/TenLecturesFortyTwoProblems.pdf), it is stated  that Lloyd’s algorithm is not guaranteed to converge to the solution of RSS. Indeed,
Lloyd’s algorithm often times gets stuck in local optima of RSS.

So from here I can assume that the function must be a non convex. *But how to proof it mathematically*.

Answer (score 1):

Let us write down the exact definition of the $k$-means objective, as taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Description), or the lecture notes you provided :

> Given a set of observations $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in\mathbb R^d$, $k$-means clustering aims at partitioning the $n$ observations inton $k$ sets $\mathbf S =\{S_1,\ldots,S_k\} $ as to minimize the *within cluster sum of squares*. Formally, the objective is to find
> $$\mathbf S^* =\arg\min_{\{\text{all possible }\mathbf S\}}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{x\in S_i}\|x - \mu_i\|^2 \tag1$$
> Where $\mu_i := \frac{1}{|S_i|}\sum_{x\in S_i}x$ is the centroid of cluster $S_i$

From this, it is clear where the non-convexity of the problem comes from : the objective function is defined over the **discrete** set $\mathscr S$ of "all possible partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of cardinal $k$" (in fact, $k$-means clustering [is a NP-hard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Complexity)). Indeed, if you look at the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) of a convex function, it is necessary for it to be defined over a convex set, but $\mathscr S$ is clearly not convex and so the objective function can't be either.

An other way to see that the objective function is not convex is to show that it doesn't have a unique minimum. To see this, first consider the following example : Consider the dataset of real numbers $\{0,1,2,3\} $ that you want to cluster. You see that for a $2$-means clustering, you could exchangeably take $\mathbf S = \{S_1:=\{0,1\},S_2:=\{2,3\}\}$ or $\mathbf S = \{S_1:=\{2,3\},S_2:=\{0,1\}\}$ and the objective would take the same value.
By the same reasoning, if $\mathbf S = \{S_1,\ldots,S_k\}$ is a minimizer of the objective $(1)$, then, for any permutation of $\{1,\ldots,k\} $ $\sigma$, $\mathbf{\tilde S} :=\{S_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,S_{\sigma(k)}\} $ is also a minimizer of $(1)$. Hence the objective function doesn't have a unique minimizer and is therefore not convex.

For this algorithm, "being stuck at a local minimum" means that the clusters are at a point where they will not change by iterating the algorithm one more time, even though a different configuration of the clusters could yield better values of the objective function. See the [Discussion section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Discussion) of the Wiki article for examples of when/how that can happen.

Comment: Thanks! @StratosFair. Can u give me insight how spectral k-means helps to avoid this local minima problem?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with that algorithm so I can't help you with that... Since it is a separate issue, I suggest you ask a new question. That way some knowledgeable people will definitely be able to help you