# what are the benefits of using Spectral K-means over Simple K-means ? and how Spectral K-means overcomes the local minimum problem of K-means?

Tags: machine-learning, spectral-graph-theory, clustering

[I have understood why K-means get stuck in local minima](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4419857/how-to-prove-that-the-residual-sum-of-squares-is-a-non-convex-function/4421638?noredirect=1#comment9253043_4421638)

> **Now I am curious to know how spectral k-means helps to avoid this local minima problem?**

According to this paper [A tutorial on Spectral](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11222-007-9033-z.pdf),

Spectral Algorithm goes in following way

1. Project data into  $R^n$  matrix
2. Define an Affinity matrix A , using a Gaussian Kernel K or an
   Adjacency matrix
3. Construct the Graph Laplacian from A (i.e. decide on a
   normalization)
4. Solve the Eigenvalue problem
5. Select k eigenvectors corresponding to the k lowest (or highest)
   eigenvalues to define a k-dimensional subspace
6. Form clusters in this subspace using k-means

**In step 6 it is using K-means. Then  how it is overcoming the local minima problem of K-means** . Moreover what are the benefits of spectral over K-means

If someone gives detailed insight upon this it will be very helpful for me.

**Edit:**- For K-means clustering, the decision boundary for whether a data point lies in cluster $C_{1}$ or cluster $C_{2}$ is linear.

> Proof of this is quite intuitive.
> Points on decision boundary will be equidistant from both the centers $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$. *Hence*,
> \begin{gathered}
> \left\|p-C_{1}\right\|^{2}=\left\|p-C_{2}\right\|^{2} \\
> \|p\|^{2}+\left\|C_{1}\right\|^{2}-2 C_{1} \cdot p=\|p\|^{2}+\left\|C_{2}\right\|^{2}-2 C_{2} \cdot p \\
> 2\left(C_{1}-C_{2}\right) \cdot p+\left\|C_{2}\right\|^{2}-\left\|C_{1}\right\|^{2}=0 \\
> \left(C_{1}-C_{2}\right) \cdot p+\frac{\left(\left\|C_{2}\right\|^{2}-\left\|C_{1}\right\|^{2}\right)}{2}=0 \\
> W \cdot p+C=0 \\
> \text { this is a hyperplane with } W=\left(C_{1}-C_{2}\right) \text { and } C=\frac{\left(\left\|C_{2}\right\|^{2}-\left\|C_{1}\right\|^{2}\right)}{2}
> \end{gathered}
> K-means cluster’s decision boundaries, leads to  a Voronoi tessellation. Problem arises when data points are arranged in a non-linear way. Where linear seperation is not possible. Hence Spectral comes into the picture.

---

**My doubt arises here , Does spectral clustering project data points to higher dimension like kernel functions and then it becomes easier to seperate the clusters?**

Comment: The main advantage of spectral clustering over k-means is that we can now learn clusters that are non-convex. The resulting clusters of a k-means procedure will always be restricted to Voronoi regions. Spectral clustering overcomes this issue.

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo Can u explain this more intuitively with mathematical proof

Answer (score 2):

I think the main advantage of spectral clustering is the fact that it does not necessarily result in a Voronoi partition of the sample space.

Consider standard k-means: Once we have found our centers $\mu_1,...,\mu_k \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ (they may correspond to a local minimum of the cost function, but we might as well assume they are the true minimizer), the $i$th cluster is given by $$C_i := \Big\{ \|x - \mu_i \| < \min_{j \neq i } \|x - \mu_j\|\Big\}$$
This is a convex set (as you can easily check) and thus we have the potentially undesirable restriction that our "true" clusters will have to be associated with a Voronoi partition of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for k-means to make sense. You can find examples where k-means fails as a result of this restriction in the answers to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means) post.

Now to spectral clustering. I think one way to see that non-convex partitions are not an issue is to note the equivalency of spectral clustering and kernel k-means (see for example [this paper](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/kdd_spectral_kernelkmeans.pdf?msclkid=57ebe5e7b81f11ecae787b5547cbe227)). Kernel k-means is essentially ordinary k-means, but instead with respect to the feature map $\phi(x)$ instead of $x$.

If for example we use the Gaussian kernel $K(x,y) = e^{-\sigma^2\|x-y\|^2}$, then $\phi(x)$ will be an element of an infinite-dimensional space.

Kernel k-means will still result in linear separation between two clusters, but in this infinite-dimensional space. Back in the sample space, the separating affine hyperplanes will be much more complicated (non-convex) structures, as you might know from (kernel) SVMs.

Comment: have understood your point but Why non-convex partitions are not an issue is for spectral clustering. If we apply simple K-means , we are applying over the real data points where in Spectral , we are applying over the Laplacian Matrix. How does it benefit the process?

Comment: Because spectral clustering is equivalent to weighted kernel k-means, which is essentially k-means in the feature space. And if you know SVMs then it is clear that you can get non-linear "boundaries" from this

Comment: okay like kernel SVM spectral maps the data points to higher dimension , so that it can be seperable?

Comment: Yes, though there may be more intuitive explanations for spectral clustering than the one I provided, which uses the results of the paper linking it to kernel k means. But I kind of like that approach because it connects to SVMs, which I know better